# Why Rails ActiveRecord generates 'count(distinct model.id)' for '.count' when 'includes' is used

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using `Rails 3.0.11` with `MySQL 5.1` and today I realized that it generates an unexpected SQL statement when calling `count` on a `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

More details:

I have the model `Profile` which belongs to an `Account`. Assuming that I do the following:

```
p = Profile.includes(:account).where("accept_threshold >= 0")
p.count
```

(`accept_threshold` is an attribute of `Profile`)

the generated SQL statement is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `profiles`.`id`) FROM `profiles` LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`id` = `profiles`.`account_id` WHERE (accept_threshold >= 0)
```

This is really a surprise to me. I would expect:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `profiles` LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`id` = `profiles`.`account_id` WHERE (accept_threshold >= 0)
```

On the other hand, the following piece of code:

```
p = Profile.where("accept_threshold >= 0")
p.count
```

generates

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `profiles` WHERE (accept_threshold >= 0)
```

Do you know why is this the case?

How can I force it to generate `COUNT(*)` instead of `` COUNT(DISTINCT `profiles`.`id`) ``?

I have tried

```
p.count(:select => "*")
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If it didn't do a count distinct it would be count of the number of `account` records where the `accept_threshold` is `>= 0`.

You are after a count of `profile` records, **not** a count of `account` records.

Comment: No. This is wrong. Both queries ```SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `profiles`.`id`) FROM `profiles` LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`id` = `profiles`.`account_id` WHERE (accept_threshold >= 0)``` and ```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `profiles` LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`id` = `profiles`.`account_id` WHERE` (accept_threshold >= 0)``` return the same count.